# Create a jQuery event after adding HTML element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamically-generated

I have a small script that creates new HTML form elements when a link in clicked via jQuery:

**Javascript**

```
var counterx = 2;
var counter = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addMoreRcpt").click(function(){
        if (counterx>10){
            alert("Only 10 reciepients are allowed");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxTr = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'RcptEml_' + counter);
        newTextBoxTr.append("<td><input type="button" id="txtRcptID_'+ counter + '"></td><td><input type="button" value="Search" id="SearchItem_'+ counter + '">
        </td>");

        newTextBoxTr.appendTo("#RcptGroup");
        counter++;
        counterx++;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
<div id="RcptGroup">
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
</tr>
<div id="1">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Search" id="SearchItem_1"></td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
</table>
<br /><a id="addMoreRcpt" href="#" >Add row</a>
```

Now for each newly created HTML form, I need to create a new jQuery event so that "Search button" will properly function. Here is the jQuery for the search button:

```
$("#searchItem_1").on('click', function() {
    $("#bg").fadeIn(400, function() {
            $("#modal").fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
    $("#modal img").on('click', function() {
        var text = $(this).siblings('.descr').text();
        $("#modal").fadeOut(400, function() {
                $("#bg").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#txtRcptID_1").val(text);    
            });
        });
    });
```

You see, the script above refers to search_Item_1 button and textbox with id txtRcptID_ID. What I need to accomplish is to create that above script every time a the "Add Row" button is clicked.

But it also needs to have correct seatchItem_# and txtRcpt_# which corresponds to the counter number when a new element is created.

For example: when I click Add Row, and the counter currently at 3, then the script adds new element with id="txtRcptID_3" AND creates a new jQuery event starting like this $("#searchItem_3").on('click', function() {

I have tried and tried and tried but without success. Anyone can help?

EDIT **

I added the following code and got pretty close, but there is still a problem with adding the value from the modal window into the text field. I added an alert function to see the value of the counter, but it mysteriously increases by one when clicking the search button:

```
newTextBoxRow.appendTo("#RcptGroup");
newTextBoxRow1.appendTo("#RcptGroup");
alert("ID number:"+counter);

$("#searchItem_"+counter).on('click', function(ev){
    $("#bg").fadeIn(400, function() {
        $("#modal").fadeIn(400);
    });
    alert("ID number:"+counter);
});

$("#modal img").on('click', function(ev) {
    var text = $(this).siblings('.descr').text();
    $("#modal").fadeOut(400, function() {
        $("#bg").fadeOut(400, function() {
             $("#txtRcptID_"+counter).val(text);    
         });
    });
});

counter++;
counterx++;
```

EDIT 2 **

Here is another try. I changed the id of the search text field to "txt_searchItem_'+ counter +'". And added this code. It functions, but still a problem though. When clicking on an image, it updates ALL text fields instead of just the one that triggered the modal window.

```
$(document).on('click', '.searchItemBtn', function(ev){
    var getID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("ID number:"+getID);
        $("#bg").fadeIn(400, function() {
               $("#modal").fadeIn(400);
        });
         $(document).on('click', '#modal img', function(ev
            var text = $(this).siblings('.descr').text();
            $("#modal").fadeOut(400, function() {
                $("#bg").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#txt_"+getID).val(text);    
                });
            });
        });
 });
```

Comment: Try creating this in a jsfiddle and posting a link here

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make `on` method to attach handlers to elements dynamically created, you should use it like this:

```
$(parent_selector).on('click', child_selector, function(ev){
    // do stuff on click
});
```

So, in your case, I would add a class to the buttons you are creating, besides the id:

```
newTextBoxTr.append('<td><input type="button" id="txtRcptID_'+ counter + '"></td><td><input type="button" value="Search" class="button_class" id="SearchItem_'+ counter + '">');
```

and would attach the handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button_class', function(ev){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The thing is I really don't understand much of jQuery. Could you write an example with the code I used above? I'd appreciate it a lot. I tried reading and playing around with on method yesterday for quite some time but never got it to run...

Comment: @Kaneda Read the "Direct and delegated events" chapter from this page if you want to understand event delegation http://api.jquery.com/on/ . Someone writing the code for you is not a long term solution :)

Comment: @Kaneda, I completely agree with Cristian. If I write the code for you today, you won't be able to solve a similar problem to this one tomorrow. Anyway, in this particular case you just have to add a class to the button you create (look at the answer, I added the class button_class) and then, instead of binding the handler to #searchItem_1, bind it to the document and filter by button_class (you can see how to do it in the answer again)

Comment: OK, I will give it a shot. Give me a couple of hours to figure this out. I'll keep you updated :D Thanks a lot for any help so far!

Comment: Davids, I am going crazy over here. I included your script to the code I posted above but it just won't work properly. I pasted to code in my original first post above (under the edited section) so you can see what I did so far. I also included an alert(counter) so I can see the current counter number. When adding a new row, the counter is correct, but when clicking the "Search" button, the counter's value increased mysteriously by 1...could you please look into this..thanks

Comment: I wouldn't go that way. It's kind of reinventing the wheel. You want to add the same functionality to several buttons, which may be created dynamically, isn't it? You can't do this binding handlers selecting elements by id, as this attribute is (should be) unique (this is a little lie, as you could accomplish that going your way, but it's complicating things with no need). How you could select several elements is doing it by class, which determine a set of elements that have something in common. So, first of all, when you create the button, have you set a class? In that case, what is the name?

Comment: Hey, I added the following class to my dynamically created buttons: class="grid_button searchItem_'+ counter +'">

Comment: Ok, first of all remove the counter of there. We want to generalize here, so if we set a different class in every button, we won't have a common class to apply a common behavior to. Change it for `searchItemBtn`, for instance. So, if you bind the handler like this `$(document).on('click', '.searchItemBtn', function(ev){}`, instead of `$("#searchItem_"+counter).on('click', function(ev){ }`, the handler will be applied to every element with the class `searchItemBtn`that is inside the `document`. Do you understand?

Comment: Notice that you'll have to do something similar with `$("#modal img").on('click', function(ev) {}`

Comment: Hey again. Thanks for the reply. I applied your changes to the script. Still won't work :(...The thing is, for the second part $("#modal img").on('click', function(ev) {}, I need the value of the image to be inserted into the dynamically added text field. How is this possible without counter?

Comment: Hey, I made a second major edit. Can you have a look at EDIT 2 in the original post. Thanks